# How to do MongoDB multiple find queries at once, using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a website for articles, like medium.com.
I want to display on the home page articles from several categories.
all articles are in the same table.
i`m doing 3 separate queries, this is currently my query:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => { 
  const food = await Post.find({ category: "food" })
  .limit(4)
  .sort("-views")
  .select(["title", "img", "author"])
  const art = await Post.find({ category: "art" })
  .limit(2)
  .sort("-views")
  .select(["title", "img", "author"])
  const sport = await Post.find({ category: "sport" })
  .limit(7)
  .sort("-views")
  .select(["title", "img", "author"])

  res.send([...food, ...art, ...sport])
})
```

Comment: Do you need different limit for each category of documents?

Comment: yes i need different limit for each category, but it will be cool to know how to do that with the same limit